# How to add header comments when altering stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure where there are no header comments. I want to add them, but whenever I try, it is not included.

In SQL Server Management Studio I :

1.Right-click my stored procedure and click modify

```
USE [ABigDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spDoWork]    Script Date: 21/08/2015 14:11:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDoWork]
      @Id uniqueidentifier,
      @Session nvarchar(50),
      @XMLData xml
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
--etc etc...
END
```

2.I paste comments above the stored procedure and run the script :

```
-- Stored Procedure
--    Author:           Dave
--    Create date:      21/08/2015
--    Description:      Does Stuff      
--  Change history
--      07/08/2015  - Overlord - Done stuff
--      06/08/2015  - Kerrigan - Done more stuff
USE [ABigDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spDoWork]    Script Date: 21/08/2015 14:11:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDoWork]
      @Id uniqueidentifier,
      @Session nvarchar(50),
      @XMLData xml
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
--etc etc...
END
```

3.When I modify the same stored procedure it appears as :

```
USE [ABigDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spDoWork]    Script Date: 21/08/2015 14:11:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDoWork]
      @Id uniqueidentifier,
      @Session nvarchar(50),
      @XMLData xml
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
--etc etc...
END
```

So how do I get the comments to appear there?

Comment: Try putting the comments underneath the `ALTER PROCEDURE`, before `AS`

Comment: Try adding `USE <your dbname where the stored procedure is created> GO` at the top then `-- Stored Procedure -- Author: Dave -- Create date: 21/08/2015 -- Description: Does Stuff
-- Change history -- 07/08/2015 - Overlord - Done stuff -- 06/08/2015 - Kerrigan - Done more stuff` your comments and then the stored procedure `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDoWork] @Id uniqueidentifier, @Session nvarchar(50), @XMLData xml WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS BEGIN --etc etc... END`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following:

```
USE [ABigDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spDoWork]    Script Date: 21/08/2015 14:11:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- Stored Procedure
--    Author:           Dave
--    Create date:      21/08/2015
--    Description:      Does Stuff      
--  Change history
--      07/08/2015  - Overlord - Done stuff
--      06/08/2015  - Kerrigan - Done more stuff

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDoWork]
      @Id uniqueidentifier,
      @Session nvarchar(50),
      @XMLData xml
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
--etc etc...
END
```

Comment: This is basically @Abhishek 's answer -- yes, you put your comment-header *just before* the ALTER/CREATE PROCEDURE line.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the meta data in ***addition*** to your procedures, tables, columns, etc. for documentation purposes.

See the following that helps when reviewing your db objects.

[Is it possible to add a description/comment to a table in Microsoft SQL 2000+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378700/is-it-possible-to-add-a-description-comment-to-a-table-in-microsoft-sql-2000)