# how can II get the list of all views and their first commented line as description

Tags: sql-server, view

I want to have a table  with two columns, first column is the name of the views, and on the second one I want to have the first commented line on the view ( I wrote a description of the view as a comment written after the CREATE line.) Is there a way to do this?

Or is there any other way to write a description in a view and display all the views in a table with their description lines?

Comment: Try to cretae Extended Properties on the views. Here is an example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378700/is-it-possible-to-add-a-description-comment-to-a-table-in-microsoft-sql-2000)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the property I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
im considering like you comment your description like below:

create view mytest
as 
/* my description */
select * from Address

Answer for your question:

select a.name, substring(text,charindex('/*',text,1),charindex('*/',text,1)-charindex('/*',text,1)+2) 'text' 
from sys.objects a join syscomments b on a.object_id=b.id where
a.type='V'
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I  intend to do

Comment: I modified it a bit to get a clean result.  my views are like this: `create view mytest as /*@ my description @*/ select * from Address` then it uses this part as description and result empty for other views that I did not use this expression

Comment: `select distinct top 99999 --a.* ,b.*, a.name as [View Name], a.modify_date, CASE WHEN charindex('/*@',text,1) <> 0 and charindex('@*/',text,1) <> 0 THEN substring(text,charindex('/*@',text,1)+3,charindex('@*/',tex‌​‌​t,1)-charindex('/*‌​@'‌​,text,1)-3) ELSE '' END 'DESC' from sys.objects a join syscomments b on a.object_id=b.id where a.type='V'  order by name asc --order by a.modify_date desc`

Answer (score 0):

Using Krishnaraj Gunasekar's method with another view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[0__View List] AS
/*@ Description of the View @*/
SELECT TOP  999999 T1.TABLE_NAME [VIEW NAME], 
CASE WHEN charindex('/*@', T1.VIEW_DEFINITION,1) <> 0  and charindex('@*/', T1.VIEW_DEFINITION,1) <> 0  THEN  substring( 
T1.VIEW_DEFINITION,charindex('/*@', T1.VIEW_DEFINITION,1)+3,charindex('@*/', T1.VIEW_DEFINITION,1)-charindex('/*@', T1.VIEW_DEFINITION,1)-3) ELSE '' END 'DEFINITION' 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[VIEWS] T1
// WHERE (T1.TABLE_NAME  like ...) 
ORDER BY T1.TABLE_NAME ASC
```